# Make only one round corner antialiased to an image

Tags: image, delphi, bitmap

everyone
I've been trying to solve the following problem in Delphi. 
I want to make take an image and to make just one antialiased round corner.
I know how to make all 4 corners round by using RoundRect. However, I don't seem to figure out how to make just one.
I've been trying to solve the problem like this:

```
procedure RoundCorner(var image: TBitmap;  w,h : integer);
//w - width of an image
//h - height of an image
//radius can be set at 150 (rounded rect radius)
// image is the timage object received as var parameter
var
   i, j :integer;
   x, y :double;
begin    
   i:= w - Trunc(radius);
   x:= 0;
   y:= radius - sqrt(sqr(radius) - sqr(x));
   while(i < w) do
   begin
      j:=0;
      while(j <= y) do
      begin
         image.Canvas.Pixels[i-1,j]:=clWhite; //a colour of your choosing or just erase this line
         j := j + 1;
      end;
     y:= radius - sqrt(sqr(radius) - sqr(x));
     x := x + 1;
     i := i + 1;
   end;
end;
```

This works, however I'm faced with 2 problems:

- The corner is not antialiased
- I want to fill the cut region with a different colour

Any suggestions are welcomed
Thanks.

Comment: You say that you know how to make all four corners round by using RoundRect. Why don't you simply make that roundRect bigger than your image and shift its position so that only one of its corners is placed above your image?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You've posted some incomplete code with a vague description. Could you [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31104647/edit) and post a minimal, compilable code that we could just copy and run in our IDEs to see the problem, please ? And optionally also an image showing the problem you described (it could be just link to an uploaded image; we can embed it for you).

Comment: @SilverWarrior: I assume that that cuts off the borders too. Probably not what he or she wants.

Comment: @TLama: But I do. Only one of the corners should be rounded. The others should simply be straight. The code is a rather simple attempt at drawing a quarter circle. The question is: how to get a partly rounded rect like that with aliasing.

Comment: @Rudy, well, the answer is then, forget on GDI (if you want to keep it simple).

Comment: guys...thanks for your replies.
Some clarifications....
I do know how to make all the corners of an image round, but my problem is to make JUST ONE.
As @TLama said how to make that partly rounded rect with aliasing.
Will edit the code to make it ok for compilation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your case "antialiasing" does mean that your image have to have a 32 bit pixel format in order to make a round transparent corner. Second thing is that you cannot access alpha channel via Canvas, you would need to access bitmap pixels directly via Scanline property or maybe to use a library like Graphics32 or AGG.

Another "modern" way to implement round corner is to use FMX and put the image inside a roundrect and clip it by the roundrect.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Can you give me more details on the "modern" approach using FMX?

Comment: Hi, i was trying to write a code in the comment, but not sure how to do it. So basically you need to create a rectangle TRectangle and TImage with rectangle as a parent. Set the size of rectangle and image equal to your bitmap, set ClipChildren property of the rectangle to True, assign Bitmap to image bitmap. 
And the last thing is to paint the whole thing to a new bitmap. You can use a PaintTo method of rectangle.

Comment: Will give a try and let you know